# Python OOP TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python-3.x, oop

The instantiate_*from_*csv  class method is supposed to read data from a CSV file named "items.csv", creates new Item objects for each row of data in the file and add the objects to the all list, then iterate through the list of dictionaries and creates a new **`Item`** object for each row of data but since price and quantity are supposed to be float and integers I had the convert them using the float() and int() methods but I am having an error

Here is the error:

```
price=float(item.get('price')),
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

Here is the code:

```
import csv
class Item:
    pay_rate = 0.8
    all = []
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: int , quantity: int):
        #run validation to the received arguments
        assert quantity >= 0, "The {quantity} quantity should be greater or equal to zero"
        assert price >= 0, "The price should be greater or equal to zero"

        #assigned to the self object      
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

        #Action to execute
        Item.all.append(self)

    def calculate_total_price(self):
       return self.price * self.quantity

    def apply_discount(self):
        self.price = self.price * self.pay_rate

    @classmethod
    def intantiate_from_csv(cls):
        with open('items.csv', 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            items = list(reader)
            # print(items)

        for item in items:
            Item(
                name=item.get('name'),
                price=float(item.get('price')),
                quantity=int(item.get('quantity')),
            )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item('{self.name}', {self.price}, {self.quantity})"


# items


Item.intantiate_from_csv()
print(Item.all)
```

Comment: Your error message tells you that `item.get` returns `None`. Did you read the docs? What situations would cause this to be the case? Did you try any debugging to confirm what's happening? What would you do to handle such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error due to extra space after comma in the heading for 'price'. Removing the extra space solved this error

[image]